# Why does $\exists x\,\ x = x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The [Wikipedia article on ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) insists that the empty set exists since it suffices for any set to exist, since the Axiom of Specification for which we always specify "false" will construct the empty set.

I agree that in the end everything works out because the Axiom of Infinity guarantees the existence of $\mathbb{N}$, but apparently this is not needed.

Directly paraphrasing the article, ZFC is "formalized," the "domain of discourse" must be nonempty, and therefore $\exists x\,\ x = x$. I don't completely understand this. Why is the assertion $\exists x$ even true (reflexivity I can accept)?

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted what $\exists x\ x=x$ means. It means "there exists a set $x$ such that $x=x$". It is not two separate statements: "$\exists x$" on its own is meaningless.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I don't see why "there exists a set $x$" is meaningless, but, even supposing it is, I still don't see why I can  accept $\exists x\,\ x=x$.

Comment: The (informal) translation into English isn't meaningless, but "$\exists x$" is formally meaningless. In any case, $\forall x\ x=x$ is an axiom of first-order logic, so if a set exists at all then it must satisfy $x=x$. Since the empty set axiom asserts that a set exists, it thus follows that $\exists x\ x=x$ is true.

Comment: You might want to try and check out these probable duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457251/axiom-of-empty-set and probably there are one or two more hiding out there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for the links. I'd argue that this isn't a duplicate however. I see how the existence of the empty set _follows_ from the existence of _a_ set, but my question isn't about the former.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have found the answer to my specific question directly in the first link, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was just going to suggest that first link.

Comment: Note that $\exists x \,\,\, x=x$ is not a well-formed formula. But $\exists x(x=x)$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *convention* that domains of discourse should always nonempty (or syntactically $\exists x: \top$ should be a tautology).

If you reject this convention, then ZFC with the axioms of infinity and empty set omitted does indeed have an empty model.

It is by no means necessary to adopt this convention; in fact, there are quite good reasons to reject it. In my experience, texts either adopt or reject this convention without comment, so it is easy enough to go for many years without even being *aware* that there are split opinions on this. To wit, my participation in the talk page for the very article you link was the first time I had ever heard of it.

It is wikipedia's convention, as far as I can tell, to reserve the phrase "first-order logic" to refer to first-order logic with the adoption this convention, and use the phrase "free logic" refer to first-order logic without this convention. (that talk page was also the first time I had ever heard the phrase "free logic")

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, it does make sense. However, as I learned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not), it seems that no convention is necessary. $\exists x\,\ x=x$ must be true, since its negation implies $\forall x\,\ x\neq x$, which is the opposite of an axiom of first-order logic.

Comment: @VF1: It is not an axiom of first-order logic! It is an axiom of first-order logic with the convention I mentioned. $\neg \forall x: x \neq x$ is ***not*** a tautology if you develop first-order logic *without* adopting this convention: in fact, the empty set models $\forall x: x \neq x$, demonstrating that its negation cannot a tautology if you develop first-order logic so as to allow empty domains of discourse.

Comment: OK - that answers everything, thanks!

Comment: It is pretty standard to include the axiom of universal instantiation (i.e. $\forall x\phi \to \phi[x/y]$) in first-order logic and to call systems which weaken this axiom free logics. I don't think it's fair to say that this is merely a convention on Wikipedia.

Comment: @GME: Isn't the problem is $\phi(y) \vdash \exists x \phi(x)$, rather than $\forall x \phi(x) \vdash \phi(y)$? At the very least, with category semantics, this is clear for interpretations into the empty set, since $\phi(y)$ is satisfied by any interpretation of $y$ as a generalized element of $\varnothing$.

Comment: @GME: I mention Wikipedia specifically, since that's the topic of discussion, and that's the extent of my knowledge on the topic. When I learned of it, all of the references I had used the phrase "first-order logic" for the weakened version rather than "free logic", and I had never felt inclined to do a survey .

Comment: @Hurkyl Right, but that rule follows from the contrapositive of the axiom of universal instantiation. The term 'free logic' goes back to the 60's (in a paper by Karl Lambert), and it's pretty widely used in philosophical logic. It surprises me that people were using "first-order logic" for free logics (or for some free logic in particular). If it's not too much trouble, I'd genuinely be interested to get references for this. Obviously, no worries if not!

Comment: @GME: I bet there is a simple explanation: e.g. that people get the idea that omitting the empty domain is merely meant as a simplifying assumption and think nothing of leaving the assumption out; that emphasizing the distinction between adopting this convention or not is needlessly nitpicky; or maybe even that category-theoretic (or other) concerns suggest that free logic is the primary object of study of first-order logic, and it is the convention of rejecting the empty domain that requires extra qualification, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @GME: I have neither handy, but one of the topics in *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* (MacLane, Moerdijk) is about first-order intuitionistic logic and geometric logic (primary aimed at studying interpretations in toposes), and does not assume non-empty domains; and IIRC, the various logics that come up in *Categories, Allegories* (Freyd, Scedrov) also do not omit the empty domain. I do not recall what else I had handy to look up at the time.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for the references - I'm not familiar with the category theoretic literature. There are interesting connections between the simplest free logic and classical logic for languages without function or constant symbols - in particular, $\phi$ is provable in CL iff $Ex_0,...,Ex_n \wedge \exists x(x=x) \to \phi$ is provable in FL (where $\phi$'s free variables are $x_0,...,x_n$). But working in FL directly is more fiddly in my experience. In any case, this is all terminological - it's just my impression that it's classical, not free logic, which is usually meant by first-order logic.

Comment: @Hurkyl And is what is presented in most standard logic text books. Anyway, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @Hurkyl Actually, it seems that this convention may be necessary to the avoid the possibility of an empty model. According to [this formulation of the Axiom of Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity), we must presuppose the existence of $\emptyset$ in order for it to be an element of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @VF1 : $\;\;\;$ While that may be true, the existence of an empty set follows from Specification plus any of the three formalizations of the Axiom of Infinity that I can think of (and uniqueness of the empty set follows from Extensionality). $\:$ Let "isempty(x)" represent "(forall y)(not (y in x)). $\:$ The "three formalizations ... I can think of" are obtained by replacing "EmptySet in $\mathbf{I}$" with one of the following: "(exists x)(isempty(x) and x in I)" or "(forall x)(isempty(x) implies x in I)" or "((exists x)isempty(x) implies (exists x)(isempty(x) and x in I))". $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer So, basically, the difference between your formalization and the one in Wikipedia is that there's an additional existential qualifier $\exists\emptyset$ in the Axiom of Infinity?

Comment: @VF1 : $\;\;\;$ One of my formalizations does not have that qualifier, and one of them has that qualifier on the _left_ side of its implication. $\:$ (Also I don't know if you realized this point: "the one in Wikipedia" is not quite formalized, because $\emptyset$ is not in the language of ZF.) $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 2):

The formula $x=x$ (where $x$ is a variable) is an axiom of first-order logic, in which set theory is formulated. By [generalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_%28logic%29) it follows that $\forall x\ x=x$ is true... so if a set exists at all then it must satisfy $x=x$. Since the axiom of infinity asserts that a set exists, it must follow that $\exists x\ x=x$ is a true statement.

As for the empty set, its existence follows from the axioms of infinity and separation. The axiom of infinity gives you that a set exists... let's call it $\omega$. The axiom of separation tells you that the following is true
$$\exists x[y \in x\ \leftrightarrow\ y \in \omega\ \wedge\ y \ne y]$$
but any witness $x$ to this sentence must be the empty set.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the quantifiers are traditionally omitted from the axioms of first-order logic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Fixed.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I would agree that this would be true if I accept the empty set axiom, but I thought the point was that we didn't need one. Without it, $\exists x\,\ x = x$ wouldn't follow from the axiom $\forall x\,\ x = x$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I found what I was looking for in Andres Caicedo's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278863/the-existence-of-the-empty-set-is-an-axiom-of-zfc-or-not) - all one has to do is negate the existence theorem and prove by contradiction!

Comment: @VF1: I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @CliveNewstead I apologize that my question may have not been clear - the empty set's existence can be proven from the axiom of specification and infinity, it's just that Wikipedia asserted that $\omega$ was not needed, and I was asking why.